# Borel functions propreties?

Tags: measure-theory

let $(X,\beta,m)$ a measurable space and $m$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure, and 
$h:X\rightarrow \mathbb C$ a Borel function ($\beta$-measurable) such that $h\in L^2(X)$.

Let $X_n=h^{-1}[-n,n]$ so can someone tell me why we will have:

$$X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$$

Comment: if $h$ is the function taking the constant value $i$ where $i^2 = -1$ then $X_n = ∅$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Calvin Khor but in this case i don t think so that your example is a borel measurable function ,,, right ?

Comment: Constant functions are definitely Borel. Did you mean for the definition to be $h:X→ℝ$?

Comment: no, i found this in a demonstration of a theorem, and it is $\mathbb C$ !!

Comment: Its not correct. You either need $ℝ$ or you need to consider preimages of other sets, e.g. balls.

Comment: hey wait, why it will be the empty set in your example we have $X_n=X$ always because $-1\in [-n,n]$ always for all n>=1

Comment: i said $i$, not -1?

Comment: aaah ok  i didn t see :) , can you tell me why a constant functon is always borel ?

Comment: the preimage of any set is either empty or the whole space, which are always in the sigma algebra.

Comment: yes right, but i think that i forget somthing , is that $h\in L^2(X)$ i ll add it

Comment: Well take $h = if$ where $f$ is your favourite strictly non-zero $L^2(X,\Bbb R)$ function. Same problem, with the same fix that I suggested.